Magnetic field of an infinite cylinder magnetized perpendicular to its axis
I'm looking for the solution to the B-field and H-field (preferably SI units) both inside and outside of an infinite cylinder with axis along $\hat{z}$ that is uniformly magnetized perpendicular to its axis, say along the $\hat{x}$ direction: $\vec{M}=M\hat{x}$. I tried to find this solution but it doesn't appear to be anywhere on the internet. I found a similar solution for that of the electric field outside of an infinite cylinder of radius R with uniform polarization $\vec{P}=P\vec{x}$, and that solution is
$\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{R^2}{2\epsilon_0}\frac{2(\vec{P}\cdot\hat{r})\hat{r} - \vec{P}}{r^2}$,
with the electric field inside being
$\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = -\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0}\vec{P}$.
Basically I want the equivalent of these expressions but for the magnetic field. My thought was to just replace $\vec{P}$ with $\vec{M}$ and $1/\epsilon_0$ with $\mu_0$ to get
$\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu_0R^2}{2}\frac{2(\vec{M}\cdot\hat{r})\hat{r} - \vec{M}}{r^2}$,
outside and
$\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = -\frac{\mu_0}{2}\vec{M}$
inside, but I am not sure if this is correct. Can anyone please help me with this solution?

Just take the rotation of B. That should give the polarisation.

I think you misunderstood my question, I'm asking about finding the solutions of the B-filed and the H-field, given a uniformly magnetized cylinder that is magnetized perpendicular to its axis.

I think you misunderstand my comment. By taking the rotation of B you should get M. If not your field is not correct

Can you please expand on this for me? I'm not aware of any equation relating the B-field to the magnetization by taking a rotation, so I can't make sense of your answer.
